# Unable to connect using SQLPLUS from the client to the server. Error raised as "Could not resolve the Connect Identifier specified"

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, sqlplus

I have 2 different servers. Both are having the Listener and TNSNAMES files correctly configured, and the listener.ora and tnsnames.ora files are also similar. And for example the service names are serv_name1 and serv_name2. And the remote login parameters are also the same as shown below:

```
SQL> show parameter remote;

remote_dependencies_mode         string   TIMESTAMP
remote_listener                  string   
remote_login_passwordfile        string   EXCLUSIVE
remote_os_authent                boolean  FALSE
remote_os_roles                  boolean  FALSE
result_cache_remote_expiration   integer   0
```

The listener also is up and running. The Tnsping on both the servers with their respective service names are pinging. 
I am able to connect to both the servers using SQL Developer. And using SQLPLUS, I am able to connect from a client system to server1 using serv_name1, but I'm unable to connecto to server2 using serv_name2.

Comment: Please can you provide the connection string that you are using (replacing username/password for made up data) and the error message that is returned. Also, please show the TNSnames settings for these two servers that are stored on your client machine.

Comment: Kindly check your connection string with the username and password. You may enter the wrong connection string with username and password

Answer (score 0):

Please try ping that service using with following statement

```
tnsping <servicename>
```

Comment: **My tnsnames.ora file is as follows:**

# tnsnames.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\tnsnames.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
WWW =
  (DESCRIPTION =
    (ADDRESS_LIST =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = 192.168.0.60)(PORT = 1521))
    )
    (CONNECT_DATA =
      (SERVICE_NAME = www)
    )
  )

Comment: **My listener.ora file is as follows:**

# listener.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\listener.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.
SID_LIST_LISTENER =
  (SID_LIST =
    (SID_DESC =
      (SID_NAME = www)
      (ORACLE_HOME = D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1)
    )
  )

LISTENER =
  (DESCRIPTION_LIST =
    (DESCRIPTION =
      (ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST = WWW-Production.Ming.int)(PORT = 1521))
    )
  )

ADR_BASE_LISTENER = D:\app\Administrator

Comment: **My sqlnet.ora file is as follows:**

# sqlnet.ora Network Configuration File: D:\app\Administrator\product\11.2.0\dbhome_1\network\admin\sqlnet.ora
# Generated by Oracle configuration tools.

# This file is actually generated by netca. But if customers choose to 
# install "Software Only", this file wont exist and without the native 
# authentication, they will not be able to connect to the database on NT.

SQLNET.AUTHENTICATION_SERVICES= (NTS)

NAMES.DIRECTORY_PATH= (TNSNAMES, EZCONNECT)

Comment: I am trying to connect from my client machine to a server(server2), but its not connecting. I also pinged using the Net Service Name, its pinging on the server2 but not connecting remotely.